# How can I solve the following errors related to jpbc library?

Tags: java

I'm using JPBC library to implement the pairing based algorithms
I've already included all the necessary jar files in java class path, but still I'm getting this error,

```
import it.unisa.dia.gas.jpbc.CurveGenerator;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.jpbc.CurveParameters;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.pairing.a.TypeACurveGenerator;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.pairing.PairingFactory;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.jpbc.Pairing;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Sensor{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    int rbits = 160;
    int qbits = 512;
    CurveGenerator crvGen = new TypeACurveGenerator(rbits, qbits);
    CurveParameters params = crvGen.generate();
    System.out.println(params);
    PairingFactory.getInstance().setUsePBCWhenPossible(true);
    Pairing pairing = PairingFactory.getPairing(params, rand);
 }
}
```

whenever I'm trying to run this code I'm getting the following error:

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'jpbc-pbc': The specified 
 module could not be found.

at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:164)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:237)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:375)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:360)
```

Comment: Which are all the jars included? Please have a look [How to use](http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/faq.html#htujpbc)

Comment: I have already included the jar files specified there,jpbc-pbc-1.2.1 jar is also included, but still getting this error... Is there any other way to load the jpbc-pbc library?

Comment: Could you share how do you run it?